# ESlint and typescript integration issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have the following problem I am trying to integrate typescript with ESlint, I have done it by installing eslint package with some additional packages basing mainly on a tutorial (
tutorial if it turns out to be helpful I can paste a link.Then after using eslint --init command I generated a file *.eslintrc*, where had all my configurations included. My goal is to have underline in my VScode Editor using Eslint. As a extra info when I use eslint --fix command it returns errors/warnings so its only underlining

I have typescript installed locally also tried globally, all necessary plugins also, deleting node_modules/checking versions of packages - don't have an idea what's wrong here. Would be very grateful for even some insights. I am using Mac pro with Mojave 10.14.6
Regards!

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "jsx": true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}
```

Unfortunately when Eslint starts still gets this kind of error in terminal output tab:

> [Error - 11:44:47 PM] Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint'
>   declared in 'project-name'/.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module
>   'typescript' Referenced from:
>   /Users/MyUser/Desktop/project-name/project-name-backend/.eslintrc.json

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the missing module alone? Try re-installing the packages giving the issues as they may have been corrupted. You could also run npm audit to repair corrupted files.

Comment: `+ typescript@3.6.3
updated 1 package and audited 3036 packages in 3.369s
found 0 vulnerabilities` -  log after running **npm install typescript**

Then deleting node_module package and install it once more and running npm audit + fix
**npm audit fix**
`up to date in 2.07s
fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 3036 scanned packages`